# Sql query to get records that match the criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to calculate the following things for a specific company i.e is `13`:

1. Total credits
2. Used credits
3. used calls

I have my data like in the below image. 
[image]

I have calculated the sum of credit_amount (`total credit`) which is `200+100+5000+100 = 5400`

Now i want to calculate the `Used Credit` which should be like this

```
200 + 100 + 5000 + 70 = 5370
```

The value `70` came because it is from the last package 
which is `credit_amount`  100 - `credit_remaining` 30 = 70.

As u can see the `recharge_date` if that date is greater than current date then package is active. so current active package is first one in above screenshot i have attached.

How can i find the Used credits?

Total calls used be in same scenario.. it will be

```
200 / 0.24 = 833.33

100 / 0.24 = 416.667

5000 / 0.20 = 25000

70 / 0.30 = 233.33
```

So the `used calls` will be the sum of above which is approximately `26483.33`

Here is my query code which is not giving the values that i need:

```
SELECT (SELECT Sum(credit_amount) 
        FROM   `company_credit` 
        WHERE  `company_id` = 13) AS total_credit, 
       Sum(credit_amount / rate)  AS used_calls, 
       Sum(credit_amount)         AS used_credit 
FROM   `company_credit` 
WHERE  `company_id` = 13 
       AND recharge_date < Now() 
ORDER  BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: I don't follow your logic. Why are taking the diff only for that single record?

Comment: what do u mean? i am making a single query for to get those records, then i will used it in php for different companies whichever company is login that time. I just want to make the above query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's due to `recharge_date` is greater then `current_date`

Comment: @SagarGangwal Nice catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Sum(credit_amount) AS total_credit, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN recharge_date < Now() THEN (credit_amount / rate) ELSE ((credit_amount-credit_reamining) / rate) END )  AS total_sms, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN recharge_date < Now() THEN credit_amount  ELSE (credit_amount-credit_reamining) END )         AS used_credit 
FROM   `company_credit` 
WHERE  `company_id` = 13 
ORDER  BY `id` DESC
```

this query will works for **`company_id = 13`**. If you calculate same logic for all company_id simply remove that **`WHERE`** condition and put **`GROUP BY company_id`**. You will get calculated records for all company.

Try above query.

Here I had simply used **`CASE WHEN`** to specify which records have remaining credit.

And using that query you can finally calculate your **`total_sms,used_credit,total_credit`** .

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan Keep it up..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(credt_amount) ,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN cr_date >
      (SELECT cur_date FROM tbl_eod_bod_stat
      )
    THEN credt_amount - credt_rem
    ELSE credt_amount
  END ) AS Used_Credit ,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN cr_date >
      (SELECT cur_date FROM tbl_eod_bod_stat
      )
    THEN (credt_amount  - credt_rem)/rate
    ELSE ( credt_amount / rate)
  END) AS rateDiv
FROM tbl_company_2;
```

Please see if this helps.